# Toggle activity for a single item in Flutters List View builder

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

How can I change the color with a toggle for a single item and not the whole list in `Flutters List View builder`? When I tap on the button of a Card, I want to change the color only of that card, and not the whole list. This is the code, which is currently toggling all of the items in the list:

```
bool _active = false;

  void _handleTap(index) {
    setState(() {
      _active = !_active;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<HTTPResponse<List<UserData>>>(
          future: _getUserList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Consumer<UserDataModel>(
                builder: (context, userData, child) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userData.userList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      UserData users =
                          userData.getUserbyIndex(index);
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
/// Here is where I toggle the colors but for the WHOLE list and not just a SINGLE item from the list
                            color: _active ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[400],
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: PopupMenuButton<UserDropDownMenu>(
                                    onSelected: (action) {
                                      switch (action) {
                                        case UserDropDownMenu.activity:
                                          _handleTap(index);
                                          break;
                                      }
                                    },
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      const PopupMenuItem<UserDropDownMenu>(
                                        value: UserDropDownMenu.activity,
                                        child: Text('Active/Inactive'),
                                      ),
                                  ),
                          }
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am also using the `Provider` for state management if that changes things.

Comment: wrap `Card` with `StatefulBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder` etc

Comment: Is this necessary? It's already a `Statefull` widget so I can just use setState, no? Also I am using the `Provider` for state management, could I do it with that?

Comment: if you dont like to wrap each item with `StatefulBuilder` whats the problem with rebuilding all the visible items actually? it shouldnt be any issue with that...

Comment: simply instead of `bool _active` use `List<bool> _active` (or `Set<int> _active`)

Comment: To answer the previous question, it is a problem since I am using the `Provider` so I don't need to use the `StatefulBuilder` nor `ValueListenableBuilder` since the widget is listening to the provider and applying changes, so I'm trying to reduce the boilerplate code, that's all. I was just trying to figure out how to change only one item in the list view and not all of them when I toggle. I tried your solution, but I get the same result in the end. Thanks for the help though, much appreciated.

Comment: if you want multiple items to be active / inactive you simply cannot have one `bool _active` variable: you need `Set<int>` which stores the indices of active items - when setting to "active" you add the index and when setting to "inactive" you remove the index from the set

Comment: can you maybe provide me an example for this current situation I have?

Comment: `class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
Set active = {};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: 32,
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
return ListTile(
title: Text('item #$i'),
tileColor: active.contains(i)? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent,
onTap: () => setState(() {
active.contains(i)? active.remove(i) : active.add(i);
}),
);
},
);
}
}
`

Comment: Mate, can you post it as an answer so I can upvote it? It is exactly what I wanted and made it working with Provider, so all is well now. :) Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink for the help, this is the answer to my question:

```
/// This is BAD since you only return one boolean value and I needed multiple items from  the list to be toggled
bool _active = false;

  void _handleTap(index) {
    setState(() {
      _active = !_active;
    });
  }

//// This is GOOD (or at least the right approach) since I needed multiple choices
/// this stores the indices of active items like @pskink said, so you can toggle each item in the list
Set active = {};

void _handleTap(index) {
    setState(() {
      active.contains(index) ? active.remove(index) : active.add(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<HTTPResponse<List<UserData>>>(
          future: _getUserList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Consumer<UserDataModel>(
                builder: (context, userData, child) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userData.userList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      UserData users =
                          userData.getUserbyIndex(index);
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
/// This is where the widget checks which item in the list is selected and change color when you trigger the _handleTap() method
                            color: active.contains(index) ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[400],
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: PopupMenuButton<UserDropDownMenu>(
                                    onSelected: (action) {
                                      switch (action) {
                                        case UserDropDownMenu.activity:
// where you call the method and the colors of the widget toggle
                                          _handleTap(index);
                                          break;
                                      }
                                    },
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      const PopupMenuItem<UserDropDownMenu>(
                                        value: UserDropDownMenu.activity,
                                        child: Text('Active/Inactive'),
                                      ),
                                  ),
                          }
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post since I want to also implement a single card only in the list of items with the provider. Here is how I solve it

provider.dart

```
List<Category> _items = categoryDummyData;

//Method for toggling single card in a list provided
    void toggleSingleCardSelection(int index) {
    for (int indexBtn = 0; indexBtn < _items.length; indexBtn++) {
      if (indexBtn == index) {
        _items[indexBtn].isSelected = true;
        print('Item ${_items[indexBtn].title} is selected ');
      } else {
        _items[indexBtn].isSelected = false;
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

categories.dart

```
final categoryItems = Provider.of<Categories>(context);
return InkWell(
      onTap: () => categoryItems.toggleSingleCardSelection(index),
      child: Card(
        color:
            //set the background color of the button when it is selected/ not selected
            categoryItem.isSelected ? kcPrimaryColor : Colors.white,
```